# How to change db.session.query value Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to display the age of babies whose age are less than 365 days, such as 60 days, 52 days, 266 days, let value divide 30, if no remainder, display integer, if not, display integer, numerator, and denominator

```
   name    days
   Alice   60
   Bob     52
   Mike    266
   Lucas   27
```

I would like to display as below style:

```
   name    days
   Alice   2
   Bob     1 22/30
   Mike    8 26/30
   Lucas   27/30
```

We use `FLASK` and `SQLALCHEMY` as below:

```
def get_baby_detail:
    data = db.session.query(Baby.name,Baby.days).filter(Basy.id == id).first()
    data.days = get_days(data.days)
    return dict(data=data)
```

But I got the error of `can't set attribute`, how to change the value of <class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result'>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to set the value of days for your DB object. I'd recommend against doing that, especially if you don't want to change what's in the DB. Why not create the dict first, manipulate the data value, and then return it? You should be able to edit the dict values without a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, use your advice, I also get the error`data_dict['data'].days = 0
*** AttributeError: can't set attribute`,  I think the reason is data( <class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result'>) is a tuple, that's why I can't change it,create dict then change it, it's also a tuple, it can not be changed

Comment: Fair enough. I've always used marshmallow_sqlalchemy to make it a dict object before trying to manipulate it. Do you need to have it as a model object? Using the `__dict__` attribute would give a cleaner dictionary to work with.

Comment: okay, I've already pasted code, could you please show me how you do it,If convenient